# how to create vertices without matching property values in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

```
My data model as below:
node:customer_entity
```

| ~id | telephone:String | Name | ~label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 969874293 | Tien | customer_entity |
| c1 | 987654145 | Henry | customer_entity |
| c1 | 954682174 | Bobby | customer_entity |

```
node:membership_card
```

| ~id | Card_No_:String | created_at | ~label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 969874293 | 22/01/2014 | membership_card |
| c1 | 190019688 | 14/08/2009 | membership_card |
| c1 | 954682174 | 08/12/2019 | membership_card |

```
I created phone_CDP node by using my query
```

```
    g.V().hasLabel('customer_entity').
    as('phone_m').values('telephone').
    as('value_phone').
    addV('phone_CDP').
    property('id',select('value_phone')).
    addE('alias').to('phone_m') `

    g.V().hasLabel('membership_card').
    as('phone_l').values('Card_No_').as('value_phone').
    addV('phone_CDP').property('id',select('value_phone')).
    addE('alias').to('phone_l')
```

```
 my output:
```

| id |
| --- |
| 969874293 |
| 987654145 |
| 954682174 |
| 969874293 |
| 190019688 |
| 954682174 |

```
 As you see i have two ids: 969874293 and 954682174 .So want to get one id value, how to do in my query?
```

```
result i want :
```

| id |
| --- |
| 969874293 |
| 987654145 |
| 954682174 |
| 190019688 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your sample graph with:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()

g.addV('customer_entity').property('telephone', '969874293').
    addV('customer_entity').property('telephone', '987654145').
    addV('customer_entity').property('telephone', '954682174')

g.addV('membership_card').property('Card_No_', '969874293').
    addV('membership_card').property('Card_No_', '190019688').
    addV('membership_card').property('Card_No_', '954682174')
```

You can add the phone_CDP vertices with:

```
g.V().hasLabel('customer_entity', 'membership_card').
    coalesce(values('telephone'),values('Card_No_')).as('phid').dedup().
    addV('phone_CDP').property('phoneId', select('phid')).elementMap()
```

> ==>[id:12,label:phone_CDP,phoneId:969874293]
> ==>[id:14,label:phone_CDP,phoneId:987654145]
> ==>[id:16,label:phone_CDP,phoneId:954682174]
> ==>[id:18,label:phone_CDP,phoneId:190019688]

You can add the edges with:

```
g.V().hasLabel('customer_entity', 'membership_card').as('vfrom').
    coalesce(values('telephone'),values('Card_No_')).as('phid').
  V().has('phoneId').as('vto').values('phoneId').where(eq('phid')).
  select('vfrom').addE('alias').to('vto')
```

> ==>e[20][0-alias->12]
> ==>e[21][2-alias->14]
> ==>e[22][4-alias->16]
> ==>e[23][6-alias->12]
> ==>e[24][8-alias->18]
> ==>e[25][10-alias->16]